# make this fluid div next to a fixed div without using float?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this code below which is making a  fluid div next to a fixed div,

is there a way to get this same result without using float?

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%">
  <div id="left" style="background-color: Blue; height: 100px; float: right; width:     200px;margin-left:10px;"></div>
  <div id="right" style="background-color: #5a71e5; height: 100px; margin-right: 210px;">
</div>
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3P9XN/4/

Comment: you have `float: right` on the #left div....

Comment: Your left div appears on right and right on left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `inline-block` is not an option since you cannot make the container on the left take up "as much space" as there is available.

If you don't want to use `float` (and suppose js is too much) I would call for the last resort:

`<table/>` - [dramatic ta -ta -ta -taaaaaa]

Where you meet a scenario where some elements should be fix sized and other should just take up as much as there is for them, then if you think of it this is what tables basically do. I know we've been booed away a lot of times from using `table`s for layouting, but if the behavior requires it, than let's not go and create complex workaround, but use something that behaves as we expect them to behave.

On the other hand `table`s are a big no-no for responsive design.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3P9XN/11/)

HTML

```
<table class="wrapper">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="right"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.right {
    background-color: Blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
.left {
    background-color: #5a71e5;
    height: 100px; 
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that in the original post, the `.left` element is place do the right of the layout... this table based solution yields a different layout, which may be nice and acceptable, but it is a solution with to a different problem.

Comment: I know, and I've changed it willingly, since a container IDd `left` that is positioned on the right is not really a `left` container and should be a `right` container. And I've also switched to classes, since I believe ids should be used carefully. And anyway Lir An's question is only based on a bet (as the updated comment does not show it anymore :) ) So I don't believe the stockmarkets are going to crash because I've renamed some containers

Comment: It is hard to guess what the OP intended, but that aside, you could have achieved the same effect using `display: table-cell` and retained the same mark-up.

Comment: I agree with Marc. `display:table-cell` is a much more elegant solution here, with the added bonus of it working just fine in a responsive design by setting it back to `display:block` when viewed on handheld devices. Please don't use HTML tables for display. We've come too far to go back to that.

Comment: I agree with both of you. But when I've put `display: table-cell` on both `.left` & `.right`. Wasn't enough. Put `display: table-row` on `.wrapper` didn't work as expected. Then I realised. Why do i want to simulate a table behavior with divs telling them to behave as table rows/cells, I could directly use just tables. http://jsfiddle.net/3P9XN/15/ . On the other hand, don't get me wrong, but as I've pointed it out in the answer, I'm not encouraging anyone to use tables for layouting. We've been there. It didn't work out. We don't want to go back.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are open to using jQuery. If yes, here's what you can do:

Get Rid of all the floats, add `display:inline-block` to the **wrapper** `div`, use jQuery to calculate the difference between total **wrapper width** minus `left div width` and set that to `right div`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left{
    background-color: Blue; 
    height: 100px; 
    width: 200px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

#right{
    background-color: #5a71e5; 
    height: 100px; 
}

#wrapper div {
    display: inline-block;
}

#wrapper{
    width:100%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#right').width($('#wrapper').width() - $('#left').width() - 20);
```

Sample Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3P9XN/12/

### Update

Added window resize detection for responsiveness

**http://jsfiddle.net/3P9XN/14/**

### Update2

Updated the solution as per Marc's suggestions, now getting outerWidth and css margin values through script. More dynamic and cleaner approach.

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(setRightWidth);

 $(window).resize(setRightWidth);

 function setRightWidth(){
        var leftmargin = parseFloat($('#left').css('margin-left'));
        var width = $('#wrapper').outerWidth(true) - $('#left').outerWidth(true) - leftmargin;
        $('#right').width(width);
 }
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/3P9XN/17/**

Comment: This technique is very useful and worth noting.  You may want to add that if the left and right blocks have padding and borders, you should use jQuery's `.outerWidth()` method.  You could also avoid the hard-coded "20" by pulling in the value of `margin-left` as a JavaScript variable. Overall, a good solution. +1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Marc. Answer updated. I know that questioner's issue has been solved but I thought this might be useful to others in future.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try **absolute positioning** since you have a pretty well defined height and widths.

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    position: relative;

}
#left {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 210px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #5a71e5;
}
```

The HTML remains the same... minus the inline styles of course.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/QypQG/